# INSERT EXEC Statement cannot be nested

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have three Procedures MainProcedure,Procedure1,Procedure2

1) In Procedure1  I just have a select statement ,

2) In Procedure2 am calling the Procedure1 and inserting the Output to a #table

3) In the main Procedure I am calling the Procedure2 and iam trying to insert the Output to a #table which throws an error

**Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Procedure2, Line 10
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.**

I can resolve this using Openrowset where I need to use specify Server Name ,is there any other way to solve this by not specifying the servername details

please find the sample procedure for reference

```
    Create Proc Procedure1
    As
    Begin
    Select 'Arun' Name, 'Pollachi' Place
    Union
    Select 'Vedaraj' Name, 'Devakottai' Place
    End
    Go



    Create Proc Procedure2
    As
    Begin
    Create Table #Table1
    (
    Name Varchar(50), Place Varchar(50)
    )
    INSERT #Table1
    Exec Procedure1
    SELECT 'Procedure2' [Source], * FROM #Table1

    DROP TABLE #Table1
    End
    Go


    Create Proc MainProcedure
    As
    Begin
    Create Table #Table1
    (
    [Source] Varchar(50), Name Varchar(50), Place Varchar(50)
    )

    INSERT #Table1
    Exec Procedure2

    select * from #Table1

    DROP TABLE #Table1
    End
    Go
```

can any one change my main procedure and make it to get executed
Thanks!!

Comment: rather than INSERT #Table1 Exec Procedure1  Use INSERT INTO #Table1 Exec Procedure1  in Procedure2

Comment: @R.S  INSERT #Table1 Exec Procedure1 doesnt works..

Comment: Use INSERT INTO #Table1 Exec Procedure1  ...or  Have a look at this thread .http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/e66c9e71-4424-4cf3-920c-6725ffc40162/

Comment: Thanks @R.S that link only gave me the solution of using open Rowset where i need to specify Server which i dont want to use

Comment: can any one change my main procedure and make it to get executed

Comment: I am also getting the above error when I run below query. Did any one suggest us whether it is possible to put stored proc result in a temp table like below.   
 CREATE TABLE #NewGlobalTempTable(
ColumnName nvarchar(150),
columnValue nvarchar(150))
INSERT INTO #NewGlobalTempTable
exec SearchAllTables '@tradeonemktg.com';
select * from #NewGlobalTempTable;

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, openrowset will work, but other than that the only ways I can think of would be:

1. Change both proc 1 and proc 2 to table based functions
2. Change proc 2 to a CLR and put all logic in there
3. Pass the tables around as table valued parameters

There's more info about the reasoning for this here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/294571/improve-insert-exec
http://dataeducation.com/revisiting-isnull-coalesce-and-the-perils-of-micro-optimization/

Comment: First link is now dead. Shame - finding it hard to understand why it's such a big drama with microsoft to return resultsets from one proc to another. I don't even have rollback in my stored proc and I get this error.

Comment: IIRC, it was related to caching - caching execution plans, caching results.