# Calling a stored procedure from another procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, exec

Using this table variable:

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue VARCHAR
DECLARE @OUT_MAIN_ERROR VARCHAR
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(50)

BEGIN
    DECLARE @TableVariable TABLE (result VARCHAR(50))

    INSERT INTO @TableVariable  
        EXEC [dbo].[DRIVEPOOL2]

    SELECT result 
    FROM @TableVariable
END
```

Using temp table:

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue VARCHAR
DECLARE @OUT_MAIN_ERROR VARCHAR
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(50)

BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #kola(result VARCHAR(50))

    INSERT INTO #kola  
        EXEC [dbo].[DRIVEPOOL2]

    SELECT * 
    FROM #kola

    DROP TABLE #kola
END
```

I get error:

> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure DRIVEPOOL2, Line 45 [Batch Start Line 3]
>   An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

I have tried with both temp table and table variable, both are throwing the error that the `INSERT EXEC` statement can't be nested.

[Drive Pool Procedure for Reference - Github](https://gist.github.com/manucr619/68417b4f5652c0d374376f2d72ad87a2)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. If you define a variable with just `varchar` - then you get a variable that can hold **exactly ONE character** of data - typically *not* what you want!

Comment: `DRIVEPOOL2` what does it return? or it just has a select statement with one column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors: "INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested." and "Cannot use the ROLLBACK statement within an INSERT-EXEC statement." How to solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795263/errors-insert-exec-statement-cannot-be-nested-and-cannot-use-the-rollback-s)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be duplicate with this thread: [INSERT EXEC Statement cannot be nested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16688753/1666800)

> This error occurs when calling a stored procedure and inserting the
>   result of the stored procedure into a table or table variable (INSERT
>   ... EXECUTE) and the stored procedure being called already contains an
>   INSERT ... EXECUTE statement within its body.

Read more about this error here:http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-8164.aspx

You can try [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to overcome this problem

```
INSERT INTO @TableVariable ( col1, col2, col3,... )
SELECT SP.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', '[Your connection string]','EXECUTE [dbo].[DRIVEPOOL2]') AS SP
```